# Adding fragments programmatically

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I was wondering if it's possible to add fragments at runTime? I have a

```
public TreeMap<String, ArrayList<Video>> mShows = new TreeMap<String, ArrayList<Video>>();
```

I'm trying to create scrollable Tabs whose texts are going to be the "String" element of the TreeMap. For each different String i will have a set of videos that correspond to that String. Is there any way that I can just have a Fragment class on which I can just do

```
Fragment fragment = new Fragment(i);
```

and then based on that "i" I can add the necessary set of videos that go on that specific Fragment?

Comment: @Emmanuel, that kind of comment can be posted beneath any question on stackoverflow.

Comment: Have you tried your suggestion?

Comment: hi @Code-Guru. I tried it with no success. I have a GridView in the layout which I'm trying to inflate, and I had problems setting the adapter  on the "onCreateView"

Comment: @aafonso1991 A better question would be posting the code that you have tried and giving details on what about it is broken.

Comment: @aafonso1991 Can you create a *complete* example that illustrates what you are trying to do? By "complete", I mean that it should be compile and recreate the exact issue that you are asking about, even if it is a compiler error or something else.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to look at the documentation for [Creating Swipe Views with Tabs](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html). You should be able to set up tabs for each one after setting up the base classes. Once you have the initial structure set up, you can easily add tabs at runtime.